# pypub module for python

Tags: python, python-3.9

Getting this error while using epub python package or you can say epub library for python , wondering what to do about it. please help..

**There are my codes:**

```
import pypub
my_first_epub = pypub.Epub('My first Epub')
my_first_chapter = pypub.create_chapter_from_url('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB')
my_first_epub.add_chapter(my_first_chapter)
my_first_epub.create_epub('OUTPUT_DIRECTORY')
```

**There are the errors:**

```
runcell(0, 'E:/python练习/untitled0.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File E:\python练习\untitled0.py:8 in <module>
    import pypub

  File D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypub\__init__.py:2 in <module>
    from epub import Epub

ImportError: cannot import name 'Epub' from 'epub' (D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\epub\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pypub not available at python 3.x, only in python 2.x. Read docs (first point at tutorial): https://pypub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_reddit.html